# Identifying two addresses

Tags: palaeography, pennsylvania, address, new-jersey

I am trying to identify the following two addresses. I have looked at past street names in Philadelphia and old maps of Vineland N.J. without success.

1. The first one is **1317 Salithos (?) St., Philadelphia PA**. It is the destination given by an immigrant arriving on Ellis Island in **1913**.

[image: List item]

The 'host' (Gregoir Lacurigi) arrived in the United States in 1911 [I cannot use the 1910 census], and lived at a different address in 1917 [ 1619 N. Philip St., from WWI draft registration card]. Many Albanians lived around the second address [betwee Oxford and Columbia (Cecil B. Moore) at that time.
Full page : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7sh81zb86kiui3/1913%2010%2027%20Keridji%20etc%20Ellis%20pt2.jpg?dl=0)

2. The second one is **SW Cor.1st (?) & Landy, Vineland N.J.**. It is the destination given by a returning American citizen in **1933** on his Ship Manifest for Ellis Island.

[image]

Landy is probably Landis Ave (or Str), but the other road is a mystery.

Comment: I think that you should split this into two questions because the sources needing to be searched in two different states are likely to be different.

Comment: "SW Cor." is "southwest corner of" So you would need to look at the corner of 1st and Landy

Comment: For #2, you should attempt to find a map that dates to 1930-1935 if possible, given that that address is from 1933.

Comment: For #1, Ancestry has the 1913 and 1914 (among other years) Philadelphia City Directories. At the front of each directory is a list of street names, followed by a list of streets that changed names. You could (a) look for your Lacurigi guy by multiple spellings and (b) look for the street by multiple spellings.

Comment: The problem is that there is/was a 4th, 3rd, 2nd... but no 1st (even at that time).

Comment: Maybe the next street over from 2nd was called 1st locally, even though it had a different name on maps, like Avenue of the Americas (6th Ave.) in NYC?

Comment: For the Philadelphia address, it would be helpful to be able to see the entire page since that might make it more obvious whether the name is indeed "Salithos" based on how the writer formed their letters.

Comment: @aem Good point. I have added a link to the whole sheet.

Comment: @cleaverkin Unfortunaly, according to the Historical Society Curator of Vineland, there was never a '1st' intersecting Landis...

Comment: Looking at the full page for the Philadelphia address, it does seem like it's "Salithos", or "Salitkos"; maybe the second to last letter could be "a"; maybe the last letter could be "o" or "a". None of those turned up any obvious matches, but maybe a further search will find one of them. Alternatively, maybe it's a phonetic spelling of a street name, or a translation of the street name into some other language?